# Makefile: strange behaviour in variable assignment

Tags: makefile, variable-assignment

consider this small Makefile:

```
test:   var ?= foo

test:
        echo $(var)
```

make's docs say that `?=` assigns a variable that has not been
assigned before (undefined).
but if assigned via commandline:

```
make var=1234
```

some random (ASCII, non-ASCII, whitespace only) characters instead of `1234` are printed to the terminal.
Using `=` instead of `?=` works as expected but cannot be used in my
case because it overrides 'inherited', exported assignments from a calling make.
Also if not using target-based but global assignment, the output
is as expected.
Where do these character sequences come from ?

Tested on linux gentoo (GNU make v3.82) and deb-wheezy (GNU make v3.81).

thanks for your hints!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with GNUMake 3.81 on OSX 10.7.5.

Comment: `var ?= foo` in your example is a goal,is it a typo?

Comment: not a typo; conditional assignment: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific

Comment: Can't reproduce this with Make 3.81 on SUSE.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue with GNU Make 3.81, but note that it occurs only when you set `var` on the command line (according to `make`'s terminology). If `var`'s value is coming from the environment, e.g. with the following command:

```
var=1234 make test
```

then everything works fine. This smells a bit like a bug of make to me, especially given the fact that the following formulation
(which according to my understanding of sections 6.5 and 6.11 of the manual ought to be equivalent to your original Makefile):

```
test: var:=$(if $(findstring undefined,$(origin var)),foo,$(var))

test:
        echo $(var)
```

works well in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a bug of GNU make. The problem is present in 3.81 and even in 3.82. For some reason a lot of systems are still using 3.81 (i.e. 2013-oct-27).  Strangly the bug is only present on Linux.  On MacOS with make 3.81 the bug does not show up.

With GIT commit ae2ab76fac (of GNU make) the problem was fixed and now the behaviour is as expected.

There is also something funny with Savannah bug #31743 which described this issue.  That one got lost when Savannah was compromised.  The bug number is now assigned to something else now.  See http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-make/2010-12/msg00009.html